# How to add a field to ElasticSearch in order to order by it in ruby gem SearchKick

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a project, where I use Searchkick gem in order to fetch records from ElasticSearch first and then do further processing on them. The guys that initially implemented it added a sort option by two fields in base options in SearchKick:

```
def base options
{
   fields: %i[catalogue_number oe_numbers],
   match: :word_start,
   misspellings: false,
   where: @conditions,
   load: false,
   order: { sale_rotation_group: { order: :desc } }, { lauber_id_integer: { order: :desc } },
   highlight: @params[:highlight]
}
end
```

`lauber_it_integer` does not exist in the application database so it must be a field in ElasticSearch that they added.

Now I want to change this and instead of current order I want to tell SearchKick to tell ElasticSearch to order the records by the fields I added to the application database: `images_count` and `parameters_count`. So probably I need to add those new fields to ElasticSearch so it knows how to order the records. I changed the order option to

```
order: { images_count: { order: :desc } }
```

but now I am getting the error:

```
Searchkick::InvalidQueryError ([400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [images_count] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"WhC4XK8IRnmmfkPJMNmV1g","index":"parts_development_20191124205133405"}]
```

This will probably involve also some extra work on ElasticSearch to add data to those new fields, however I know very little about ElasticSearch. Could you give me some indications or hints on how I could solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add elasticsearch indexes to each new field you want to be orderable / searchable.

[Here](https://iridakos.com/programming/2017/12/03/elasticsearch-and-rails-tutorial) is a decent guide to setting one up from scratch which explains all the basic concepts, elasticsearch has its own schema so you need to get that to match your new one.

The example they give is:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings do
    mappings dynamic: false do
      indexes :author, type: :text
      indexes :title, type: :text, analyzer: :english
      indexes :body, type: :text, analyzer: :english
      indexes :tags, type: :text, analyzer: :english
      indexes :published, type: :boolean
    end
  end
end
```

You should see a similar section on whatever model you're searching for.

Just add the fields you want to have indexed to the model file, and then from console call (replacing `Post` with your model name):

```
Post.__elasticsearch__.delete_index!
Post.import force: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution on `searchkick` documentation.

Update `search_data` definition

```
def search_data
  {
    ...,
    images_count:         images_count,
    parameters_count:     parameters_count
  }
end
```

Update searchkick otpions:

```
def base options
{
   fields: %i[catalogue_number oe_numbers],
   match: :word_start,
   misspellings: false,
   where: @conditions,
   load: false,
   order: [{ images_count: { order: :desc } }, { parameters_count: { order: :desc } }],
   highlight: @params[:highlight]
}
end
```

Reindex the model

`Part.reindex`

It will automatically add indexes.